# How to copy big object into omp task inside a loop?

Tags: c++, openmp

I am using a while loop to start several omp tasks. Each task needs to copy a rather big object (as a firstprivate). Due to my setup, the big object (in this example a vector) would naively be copied twice:

```
struct bigStruct {
    bool next() {
        /* do something with m_bigVector */
    }

    std::vector<int> m_bigVector;
    /* other (big) data members */
};

bigStruct s;

#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp single
    while (s.next()) {
        auto obj = s.m_bigVector; //copy the first time

        #pragma omp task firstprivate(obj) //copy the second time
        {
            /* do something with obj */
        }
    }
} //end parallel
```

gcc optimization (-O3) do not seem to optimize away the two copy steps in any way.
A (not-so-elegant) solution is by using explicit `new/delete`:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp single
    while (s.next()) {
        auto obj_ptr = new std::vector<int>(s.m_bigVector); //copy once

        #pragma omp task firstprivate(obj_ptr) //copy only the pointer
        {
            /* do something with obj */


            delete obj_ptr; 
        }
    }
} //end parallel
```

Is there a more `modern/elegant` approach to solve this? Maybe a way to tell the task to move the object instead of copying it?
Note that I don't want to copy the whole `bigStruct` as it contains other big data members.

Comment: If you know it will be copied 'a second time', couldn't you just take a reference for `obj` ?

Comment: I was thinking of that too, but I read in a openmp tutorial that "A firstprivate variable must not have a reference type." I checked a simple example where I put a reference and it works (gcc-9.1), but I am not sure that it will work correctly on every system/compiler and for more complicated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news!

> A firstprivate variable must not have a reference type.

is outdated as of OpenMP 4.5 (2015). There is currently no such restriction. There is one requirement:

> If a list item in a `firstprivate` clause on a worksharing construct has a reference type then it must bind to the same object for all threads of the team.

But that doesn't apply - the `task` construct is not a worksharing construct and is not encountered by multiple threads anyway.

To full understand what the standard mandates:

(regarding list item privatization)

> If the type of a list item is a reference to a type `T` then the type will be considered to be `T` for all purposes of this clause.
>
> A new list item of the same type, with automatic storage duration, is allocated for the construct.
>   The storage and thus lifetime of these list items last until the block in which they are created exits.
>
> For each variable of class type:
>
> • If the `firstprivate` clause is not on a `target` construct then a copy constructor is invoked to perform the initialization

So you can safely do:

```
auto& obj = s.m_bigVector;
#pragma omp task firstprivate(obj) // call copy ctor once
```

Unfortunately you cannot

- Use `const auto&` because then the type of `obj` would be const as only the reference is removed.
- Move obj into a `firstprivate` declaration. That would be nice, but only applies to tasks where only a single thread actually encounters the data-sharing clause.